# Smooth double jump Unity 2D platformer

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a smooth double jump mechanic for Unity 2D, platformer game but right now the second jump is bigger if you jump right after the initial jump and I want to have it the other way around the double jump should throw you higher if you press it later like in most 2D platformer games this is my code

```
       private void Update()
       {
            grounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(transform.position, GroundedEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            if (grounded || !doubleJumpUsed)
            {
                playerRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower));
            }
            if (!grounded && !doubleJumpUsed)
            {
                doubleJumpUsed = true;
            }
            UpdateJumpingAnimator();
        }

        private void UpdateJumpingAnimator()
        {
           if (grounded)
           {
               doubleJumpUsed = false;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
playerRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

In this case it is necessary to reduce the value of the variable JumpPower

Comment: You used any input controllers for control hero?

Comment: No I use my own script to move it.

Comment: playerRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower), ForceMode2D.Impulse); use this in FixedUpdate not in Update!!!

Comment: It's absolutely the same I don't see what you are trying to do using the FixedUpdate.

Comment: FixedUpdate used for operations by physics, try

Comment: "It's absolutely the same" I already tried that with no result.

Comment: Show options on player rigidbody component

Comment: May be try change rigidbody2D.velocity value? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not sure if there's a pretty way to do what you're asking. But have you tried tieing JumpPower into a timer? In other words, the longer the character is in the air the more time has elapsed, the more force is applied to the 2'nd jump when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried to achieve the double jump on a sphere(player) and here is my code. See if it helps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerDoubleJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 5;
    public float groundDistance = 0.5f;

    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    bool canDoubleJump;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    /*bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 
groundDistance);
    }*/

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 
groundDistance))
            {
                rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.up * jumpForce;
                canDoubleJump = true;
            }
            else if (canDoubleJump)
            {
                rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.up * jumpForce;
                canDoubleJump = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```